# On Github, is there an enforced relationship between issues and pull requests?

Tags: git, github, open-source

I am planning to contribute to an open source project on Github for the first time and I see that there are many open "issues" in the repository.

When deciding what to work on, do I have to choose from this list of issues or can I create a pull request for a commit that was never asked for or documented as an "issue"?

Does this rule vary from project to project or is there a typical answer to this?

Comment: AFAIK, you don't have to create an issue before submitting a pull request but you'll have to describe the goal of the pull request exactly as if you reported issue.

Comment: It varies by project. Most bigger open-source projects have a "How To Contribute" guide or similar that might answer this question for you for that specific project.

Comment: Some projects like that an issue is created before doing a pull request. That way you could gather informations from maintainers that could even tell you that your PR to be won't be merge because not in phase with the project ;-) For a new contributor, it's always a good thing to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Your pull requests generally don't have to respond to specific issues, but you should check if the project has a `CONTRIBUTING.md` file that details how best to help out.

[One example is the Atom editor's contributor guidelines document.](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)